# Looping through cells of table and using ForEach onClick - Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I've created a table using javascript and populated each cell with the names of months. I want to assign an OnClick function which checks what cells are clicked and sends the name to console.log(). Here is what I've managed so far:

```
    <script>

    function monthCalender() {

        var chkbxMonth = document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxMonth');
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

        var tbl = document.createElement("table");
        tbl.id = ("Month_Table");

        var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

        for (row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
            var tblRow = document.createElement("tr");

            for (col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                var a = (row * 3) + col;

                cell.id = "Month_" + a;
                cell.setAttribute("data-val", chkbxMonth[a].querySelector(".checkboxMonth").id);

                var cellContent = document.createTextNode(chkbxMonth[a].textContent);

                cell.appendChild(cellContent);

                tblRow.appendChild(cell);

            }
            tblBody.appendChild(tblRow);

        }
        tbl.appendChild(tblBody);

        body.appendChild(tbl);

        tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");


        $(function () {
            $('td').click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('on');
            })
        });



        var rows = document.getElementById("Month_Table").rows;
        for (var p = 0; p < rows.length; p++) {

            var col = rows[p].getElementsByTagName("td");

            for (q = 0; q < col.length; col++) {
                console.log(col[q]);

                //col.forEach(k => k.addEventListener('onClick', event => {

                //    console.log("Cell has been checked");

                //}));
            }


        }




    }



    monthCalender();

</script>
```

The problem I'm having is when I write console.log(col[q])(found near the bottom of the script) it sends only the cells of the first column to the console rather than all the cells. Am I iterating through the cells incorrectly or am I missing another loop?

Also, where would I add the onclickAddevent listener?

Comment: If you want to add a listener on each row, why not do someting like `document.querySelector("#Month_Table td").addEventListener('click', (e) =>{console.log(e.target, e.target.innerHTML);})`. Also, be aware that you are adding a click listener on all the td on the page with `$('td').click(...)` (not only the ones in the table you created earlier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to assign OnClick to the columns. You need to assign it to each cell. Here is an example to achieve that:

I used "Month_Table" id that you assigned in your code.

```
document.querySelectorAll('#Month_Table td')
.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Dos something here
    console.log("clicked")
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you mixing jQuery and regular javascript?
Seems jQuery is already integrated in your project, so you can bind the click event to all cells without a loop:

```
    $("td","#Month_Table").click(function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass('on');
        console.log("Cell has been checked");
    };
```